In general , how do we remove the UserId from the wonderpush in flutter?
We can add the userId using ,

await Wonderpush.setUserId("#####");

But how do we remove the userId.
There is only option to add string but not the null, so that I can remove it. If I use something else than null like  _ , then there is the problem removing it.
